# Filter out everything of a certain color using openCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning

I have pictures of buildings I want to classify, and I want to get rid of the sky as I think it is messing with my classifier. I know that OpenCV has a function called inRange, that takes in the image and blacks out everything not in the range of the two color bounds that you provide. I was wondering if there was a function that literally did the opposite. Or another way I can accomplish what I want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`cv2.InRange` creates a mask, which basically means it creates an image of the same size where the pixel values that are in the range are 255, and the values outside the range are 0.

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20inRange(InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20lowerb,%20InputArray%20upperb,%20OutputArray%20dst)

If you want to have the opposite of that you can take the output of `cv2.inRange` and perform a `bitwise_not`:

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-not

If you want to then use that to black out the pixels in your original image you could do a `bitwise_and`:

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and

So I would do something like:

```
mask = cv2.inRange(img, (255, 0, 0), (100, 0, 0)) # modify your thresholds
inv_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
no_sky = cv2.bitwise_and(img, inv_mask)
```